# Data/database framework in flash/flex

Tags: database, flash, actionscript-3, flex4.5

I have a flash project that connect with a server. I get all data from the server as raw tables as XML. So I have to do the server logics client side. (Don't ask why!)

I have looked for a framework or some code base that have solved this. A framework that can do mapping of keys asf. Basically a frame work that stores the data and handles retrieving of the data like SQL.

Ie. I can get user with the userid without iterating through all the instances. This gets more  complex when you have more id in the same table.

So is there a data framework for flash out there?

(the HTML 5 sqlLight would be great if more browsers supported it)

Answer (score 1):

E4x will allow you to run some pretty sophisticated queries against your XML.  Check out http://dispatchevent.org/roger/as3-e4x-rundown/

Comment: Looks cool. But is it faster than looking up in a dictionary?
thePeople.person.(@name == "Roger Braunstein").age
vs.
thePeople["Roger Braunstein"].age

Comment: It has less potential for memory leaks.  I haven't seen where anyone has posted benchmarks on these two side by side.

Comment: Note that if you have two entries for Roger Braunstein (quite likely given the nature of databases), the dictionary method will only give you the first,

Answer (score 0):

I feel obliged to point out what you probably already know - sending the tables like that is insecure, wasteful and kind of stupid. EDIT: Unless you actually NEED all that data in the swf, in which case it's fine :)

I don't *think* there is a framework for this, so you would probably have to build it yourself. You should be able to put all the rows in an array and then use one or more Dictionary(s) as a database index. Eg:

```
trace(_data[_idIndex[100]]);
trace(_data[_nameIndex["jonatan"]]);
```

All you need to do to get there is build the indexes;

```
_nameIndex = new Dictionary();
_idIndex = new Dictionary();
for(var i:int = 0; i<_data.length; i++) {
 _idIndex[_data[i].id] = i;
 _nameIndex[_data[i].name] = i;
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: For non-unique identifiers you might have to store an array of indexes in the dictionaries, instead of the indexes themselves. You could also store a direct reference to the object that it's indexing instead of its place in the _data-array.

Comment: As I wrote "don't ask", the server-backender wants to save the server from database operations (joins ect). I have not been able to convince him otherwise. I can see the point that there is a lot of users on the server, our users have high end machines, so pushing the operations to them works and save the serverload, thus being able to handle more load. We don't send all information from tables, some is filtered out, so it is not insecure. 
But it is stupid that I have to create a whole database and SQL language that exist already. That's why I'm looking into it.
I can do it so it is not that.

Comment: @Christen "wants to save the server from database operations (joins ect)". Run, just run.  I'm am the furthest thing from a DBA but if he doesn't want to use a database as a database I would be a little worried about his competency in other areas.  Basically he is substituting software specialized for this type of problem (databases) with software that is made to be very general ( Flash VM ).  XML is okay, but it can become unwieldy if the node count gets high.  NEVER reinvent the wheel.